# SELECT * FROM cursor returned as OUTPUT cursor from a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-cursor

How can I select the data from a cursor returned as OUTPUT cursor from a stored procedure in Oracle?
Is any a way another faster way than creating a temporary table and loop the cursor and inserting row by row?

Comment: Maybe/probably. Skip PL/SQL and cursor loop and do everything at SQL level, using a single INSERT statement. For more info, you'll probably have to explain the problem a little bit better, possibly by including piece of code which illustrates it.

Comment: @Littlefoot, I have to get the data from an Oracle stored procedure that returns a cursor at output and import the data into another database.